# How can i add a title for jquery UI dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How to add a `title` for the `JqueryUI dialog box` for this case. This `dialog` box opens as per the `model` name in ruby on rails.

### Example of the html page:

```
<%= link_to pro_generic_lookup_data_path("Enr::Rds::Section2009", format: :js), data: {remote: true} %>
```

Here, the `pro_generic_lookup_data` is have the option of `uidialog box.` So, it would open depend upon the `model name("Enr::Rds::Section2009")`.

### JavaScript

```
var generic_lookup_Enr_Rds_Section2009_selected = function(id, to_s) {
  var section_value = $(".cross-reference-section-value");
  var section_id = $(".cross-reference-section-value-id");
  var section_clear_img = $(".cross-reference-section-clear-img");
  section_id.val(id);
  section_value.text(to_s);
  section_value.css('display', 'inline');
  section_clear_img.css('display', 'inline');
  $(section_clear_img).on('click', function() {
    section_value.text('')
    section_id.val('')
    section_clear_img.css('display', 'none');
  });
  var question_link = $('#question_picker').attr('href');
  question_link = question_link.replace(/\?+$/, '');
  question_link = question_link + '?columns[enr_rds_section_id]=' + id;
  $('#question_picker').attr('href', question_link);
  $("#modal_popup").dialog("destroy");      
};
```

I have three fields like this same. So, I need to give a separate titles for all the three fields. Thanks!

Comment: You could always minify/compress/uglify the method.  Try http://javascriptcompressor.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than some basic formatting and using chained selectors where applicable, the code is fine.

```
var generic_lookup_Enr_Rds_Section2009_selected = function(id, to_s) {
    var $section_value = $(".cross-reference-section-value");
    var $section_id = $(".cross-reference-section-value-id");
    var $section_clear_img = $(".cross-reference-section-clear-img");

    $section_id.val(id);    
    $section_value.text(to_s).css('display', 'inline');

    $section_clear_img.css('display', 'inline').on('click', function() {
        $section_value.text('')
        $section_id.val('')
        $section_clear_img.css('display', 'none');
    });

    var question_link = $('#question_picker').attr('href');
    question_link = question_link.replace(/\?+$/, '');
    question_link = question_link + '?columns[enr_rds_section_id]=' + id;
    $('#question_picker').prop('href', question_link);

    $("#modal_popup").dialog("destroy");      
};
```

Comment: Does we need the dollar sign after we declared the variable?

Comment: It is the marker for indication that we store jquery object. Kind of nice jquery code style

Comment: Thanks Roman! I have an issue with the question picker of this javascript. The question_picker add the section_id of the existing href. After reselect the section_id, the question_picker doesn't change the section-id. How to resolve this? Thanks